# How to increase Testcoverage for Class that interacts with a Database?

Tags: java, mysql, junit, test-coverage

I got a Java class called PatientRepositoryImpl, which contains some methods, that insert, delete or update Data in a MySql Database.
I've also written some Unit Tests for this class.
When i check the Coverage of my tests, i only get 59%, although almost every line of Code is marked green by the Coverage tool, except the SQL Exceptions.
I am new here and hope i did everything right, would be very thankful if someone could help me.

Here the code for my Repository and the Tests.

```
public class PatientRepositoryMySqlImpl implements PatientRepository {


private DatabaseConnection connection;
private PatientGenerator patientGenerator;


public PatientRepositoryMySqlImpl(DatabaseConnection connection, PatientGenerator patientGenerator) {
    this.connection = connection;
    this.patientGenerator = patientGenerator;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see com.id.hl7sim.PatientRepository#insertPatient()
 */
@Override
public void insertPatient(Patient patient) {
    if (!patient.isValid()) { 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Incomplete Patient");
    } else {
        String insert = "INSERT INTO tbl_patient(lastname, firstname, gender, birthday) VALUES('"
        + patient.getLastname() + "', '" + patient.getFirstname() + "', '" + patient.getGender() + "', '"
        + patient.getBirthday().toString() + "');";
        try (Connection dbConnection = connection.getDBConnection();
             Statement statement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insert)) {
            statement.executeUpdate(insert);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see com.id.hl7sim.PatientRepository#insertListOfPatients()
 */
@Override
public void insertListOfPatients(List<Patient> allPatients) {
    for (Patient patient : allPatients) {
        insertPatient(patient);
    }
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see com.id.hl7sim.PatientRepository#getRandomPatient()
 */
@Override
public Patient getRandomPatient() {
    Patient patient = new Patient.Builder().build();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_patient ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
    try (Connection dbConnection = connection.getDBConnection();
         Statement statement = dbConnection.createStatement();) {
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
        rs.next();
        setPatientBasicData(patient, rs);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return patient;
}

private void setPatientBasicData(Patient patient, ResultSet rs) {
    try {
        patient.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
        patient.setLastname(rs.getString("lastname"));
        patient.setFirstname(rs.getString("firstname"));
        patient.setGender(rs.getString("gender"));
        patient.setBirthday(parseBirthday(rs.getString("birthday")));
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

public LocalDate parseBirthday(String birthday) {
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(birthday);
    return localDate;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see com.id.hl7sim.PatientRepository#admitRandomPatient()
 */
@Override
public Patient admitRandomPatient() {
    Patient patient = getRandomPatient();
    patient.setDepartment(patientGenerator.getRandomDepartment());
    patient.setWard(patientGenerator.getRandomWard());
    patient.setAdmissionDateTime(LocalDateTime.now());
    patient.setStatus("I");
    String insert = "INSERT INTO tbl_inpatients(id, ward, department, admissionDate, patientStatus) VALUES('"
                    + patient.getId() + "', '" + patient.getWard() + "', '" + patient.getDepartment() + "', '"
                    + patient.getAdmissionDateTime().toString() + "', '" + patient.getStatus() + "')";
    try (Connection dbConnection = connection.getDBConnection();
         PreparedStatement statement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insert)) {
        statement.executeUpdate(insert, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        ResultSet keys = statement.getGeneratedKeys();
        keys.next();
        patient.setCaseId(keys.getInt(1));
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return patient;
}

public Patient getRandomInpatient() {
    Patient patient = new Patient.Builder().build();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_inpatients ip, tbl_patient p WHERE p.id = ip.id  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
    try (Connection dbConnection = connection.getDBConnection();
         Statement statement = dbConnection.createStatement();) {
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
        rs.next();
        setPatientBasicData(patient, rs);
        setPatientCaseData(patient, rs);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return patient;
}

public void setPatientCaseData(Patient patient, ResultSet rs) {
    try {
        patient.setWard(rs.getString("ward"));
        patient.setDepartment(rs.getString("department"));
        patient.setAdmissionDateTime(parseLocalDateTime(rs.getString("admissionDate")));
        patient.setStatus(rs.getString("patientStatus"));
        patient.setCaseId(rs.getInt("case"));
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

public LocalDateTime parseLocalDateTime(String localdatetime) {
    localdatetime = localdatetime.replace("T", "");
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:ss.SSS");
    LocalDateTime formattedLocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(localdatetime, formatter);
    return formattedLocalDateTime;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see com.id.hl7sim.PatientRepository#transferRandomPatient()
 */
@Override
public Patient transferRandomPatient() {
    Patient patient = getRandomInpatient();
    patient.setPriorWard(patient.getWard());
    patient.setPriorDepartment(patient.getPriorDepartment());
    patient.setDepartment(patientGenerator.getRandomDepartment());
    patient.setWard(patientGenerator.getRandomWard());
    String update = "UPDATE tbl_inpatients SET ward='" + patient.getWard() + "', department='"
            + patient.getDepartment() + "' WHERE id='" + patient.getId() + "'";
    try (Connection dbConnection = connection.getDBConnection();
         Statement statement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(update)) {
        statement.executeUpdate(update);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return patient;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see com.id.hl7sim.PatientRepository#dischargeRandomPatient()
 */
@Override
public Patient dischargeRandomPatient() {
    Patient patient = getRandomInpatient();
    patient.setDischargeDateTime(LocalDateTime.now());
    insertFormerPatient(patient);
    String delete = "DELETE FROM tbl_inpatients WHERE `case`=" + patient.getCaseId();
    try (Connection dbConnection = connection.getDBConnection();
         Statement statement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(delete)) {
        statement.executeUpdate(delete);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return patient;
}

public void insertFormerPatient(Patient patient) {
    String insert = "INSERT INTO tbl_formerpatients(`case`, `id`, ward, department, admissionDate, dischargeDate) VALUES('"
            + patient.getCaseId() + "', '" + patient.getId() + "', '" + patient.getWard() + "', '"
            + patient.getDepartment() + "', '" + patient.getAdmissionDateTime().toString() + "', '"
            + patient.getDischargeDateTime().toString() + "')";
    try (Connection dbConnection = connection.getDBConnection();
         Statement statement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insert)) {
        statement.executeUpdate(insert);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

public int countInpatients() {
    int numberOfPatients = 0;
    String query = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS numberOfPatients FROM tbl_inpatients";
    try (Connection dbConnection = connection.getDBConnection();
            Statement statement = dbConnection.createStatement();) {
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs.next()) {
            numberOfPatients = rs.getInt(1);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return numberOfPatients;
}

public int countPatients() {
    int numberOfPatients = 0;
    String query = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS numberOfPatients FROM tbl_patient";
    try (Connection dbConnection = connection.getDBConnection();
            Statement statement = dbConnection.createStatement();) {
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs.next()) {
            numberOfPatients = rs.getInt(1);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return numberOfPatients;
}
```

Tests

```
public class PatientRepositoryMySqlImplTest {

PatientRepository testPatientRepository;

Patient testPatient;

Patient testPatientTwo;

List<Patient> testBothPatients;

DatabaseConnection testConnection;

PatientGenerator testPatientGenerator;

Firstnames testFirstnames;

Lastnames testLastnames;

Departments testDepartments;

Wards testWards;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    testDepartments = JAXB.unmarshal(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("departments.xml"), Departments.class);
    testWards = JAXB.unmarshal(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("wards.xml"), Wards.class);
    testLastnames = JAXB.unmarshal(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("lastnames.xml"), Lastnames.class);
    testFirstnames = JAXB.unmarshal(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("firstnames.xml"), Firstnames.class);

    testPatientGenerator = new PatientGeneratorImpl(testFirstnames, testLastnames, testDepartments, testWards);

    testPatient = testPatientGenerator.randomizeNewPatient();

    testPatientTwo = testPatientGenerator.randomizeNewPatient();

    testBothPatients = new ArrayList<Patient>();

    testConnection = new MySqlConnection();

    testPatientRepository = new PatientRepositoryMySqlImpl(testConnection, testPatientGenerator);

    testPatientRepository.admitRandomPatient();

}

@Test
public void testAdmitRandomPatient() {

    testPatient = testPatientRepository.admitRandomPatient();

    assertTrue(testPatient.isValid());
}

@Test
public void testGetRandomInpatient() {

    testPatient = testPatientRepository.getRandomInpatient();

    assertTrue(testPatient.isValid());
}

@Test
public void testDischargeRandomPatientValid() {

    testPatient = testPatientRepository.dischargeRandomPatient();

    assertTrue(testPatient.isValid());
    assertTrue(testPatient.getCaseId() != 0);
}

@Test
public void testDischargeRandomPatientDatabase() {

    int beforeDischarge = testPatientRepository.countInpatients();
    testPatient = testPatientRepository.dischargeRandomPatient();
    int afterDischarge = testPatientRepository.countInpatients();

    assertTrue(afterDischarge == beforeDischarge - 1);

}

@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void testInsertPatientWitIncompletePatient() {

    testPatient.setFirstname("");

    testPatientRepository.insertPatient(testPatient);
}

@Test
public void testTransferRandomPatient() {

    testPatient = testPatientRepository.transferRandomPatient();

    assertTrue(testPatient.getDepartment() != testPatient.getPriorDepartment());
}

@Test
public void testInsertPatient() {

    int numberOfPatients = testPatientRepository.countInpatients();

    testPatientRepository.insertPatient(testPatient);

    assertTrue(testPatientRepository.countInpatients() >= numberOfPatients);
}

@Test
public void testInsertListOfPatients() {

    testBothPatients.add(testPatient);
    testBothPatients.add(testPatientTwo);

    int countInpatientsBeforeInsertion = testPatientRepository.countPatients();

    testPatientRepository.insertListOfPatients(testBothPatients);

    int countInpatientsAfterInsertion = testPatientRepository.countPatients();
    assertTrue(countInpatientsAfterInsertion > countInpatientsBeforeInsertion);

}
```

Edit:

```
@Test
public void mockThrowsException() {

    PatientRepository testPatientRepository = mock(PatientRepositoryMySqlImpl.class);

    when(testPatientRepository.getRandomPatient()).thenThrow(SQLException.class);

    testPatientRepository.admitRandomPatient();

}
```

Comment: use mocks that throw Exceptions

Comment: For a Unittest, you should mock at least the DatabaseConnection. Instead of verifying that data was written to the DB, you just need to verify the correct statements were issued; the Unit(or Integration-)tests for the DBConnection need to then verify that those are producing the correct result.

Comment: Thank you very much so far! I am new into Mocking, but got a lot of information here and tried some stuff. Could you take a look at my edit, did you mean like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I completely agree that in order to increase the coverage you should definitely "simulate" the scenario that something goes wrong and `SQLException`s are thrown, let me introduce another approach that will also answer the question but hopefully give you another perspective.

JDBC is pretty cumbersome, and the tests that will throw SQL exceptions will probably not be the most pleasant tests to write. In addition, I see that you don't really deal with exceptions, and just log them in a console.

So maybe instead of trying to struggle with this, maybe you should consider to not work directly with JDBC but use some library that will wrap the hassle of JDBC usage for you. For example of such a library, take a look onto [Spring JDBC Template](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/jdbc.html), I know it's a pretty old stuff, but hey, working directly with JDBC is also probably not the most modern approach, so I'm trying to make fewer changes but still gain a value. Moreover one may say that its old and not fancy, I would say, a battle-tested library, that can be even without Spring itself.

Now since it wraps the JDBC Exception handling, among other things, the point is that you won't have to cover these cases at all. So your coverage will increase naturally.

Of course other low level and no-so-low level alternatives exist (like [JDBI](http://jdbi.org/), or [JOOQ](https://www.jooq.org/) to name a few), but this a different story, all of them will increase the coverage in a sense of a question you've asked.

Comment: Thank you very much @Mark Bramnik, I appreciate your help and will try this on my project now.

Comment: Well, it took me some time, but finally I got all changes done. My Coverage increased very well and I also think, the solution with Spring JDBC Template is much butter, I like it - Thank You!